# Expo reactnative FileSystem is not saving my file on my device

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, expo-file-system, expo-permissions

I used different method to do this and all didnt work but when I tried downloadasync it showed little light but didnt work.

```
const downloadFile = async (url) => {
    try {

      console.log("Started");
      setLoadingModal(true)
      // const response = await fetch(url);
  
      console.log(url);
      // Get the file name from the URL or the Content-Disposition header
      const fileName = url?.split('/')[url?.split('/').length-1]
      
      //path to download
      const path=FileSystem.documentDirectory+"FirstOG/"

      FileSystem.getInfoAsync(path).then(({exists}) => {
        if (!exists) {
          console.log(exists);
          FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(path)
        } else {
          null
        }
      })

      let file= await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
        url,
        path+ fileName,      
      )

      console.log(file);
    
      Linking.openURL(file.uri)
      console.log("go");
  
  
      console.log(`File saved to ${file.uri}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error downloading file:', error);
    }finally{
      setLoadingModal(false)
    }
  
 
};
```

It didnt save the file to my mobile device and i hav checked the route well and still nothing

If I use CreateDownloadResumable it gave this error below
`[TypeError: 0, _expoModulesCore.uuidv4 is not a function (it is undefined)]`

I tried permissions but nothing changed
I even built it and nothing

i was expecting my file to be saved unto the phone.
I tried using permission and other things.

Comment: I may just be reading this wrong but it looks like you are referencing a variable that is not defined. Above in your code you have a line:
```const { uri } = await downloadResumable.downloadAsync();```
But I can't see anywhere where downloadResumable is defined.

Comment: @DustinForsyth I have removed it but its still giving same error but no download resumable error

Comment: I would maybe try to uninstall and reinstall the `expo-file-system` package I know that uuidv4 is a dependency of that package so maybe something just went wrong with the nom install.

Comment: @DustinForsyth still same thing, no file was saved

Comment: Does it not save the file on android or iOS or is it just one or the other?

Comment: @DustinForsyth both

Comment: Weird I am not sure what else to try then! Good Luck! Hopefully someone else will have an idea.